# Removing folder shortcuts from gnome-panel

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I am using 12.10, GNOME classic desktop. I believe the top bar (Applications/Places menus; wireless icon, sound volume icon, clock, Bluetooth icon, etc.) comes from gnome-panel, but I am not sure. Anyway, I accidentally dragged a folder onto it and now it displays a nice icon proving shortcut access to the folder. I'd like to remove this icon but I can't seem to be able to "drag it *out* of there".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>RIGHT CLICK</kbd> to edit items on the panel in Gnome classic.